# Android Socket, AsyncTask, Handler memory leak

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm feeling frustrating. After few day, I raise the white flag and ask for help.
I've used this code sample:

https://github.com/sht5/Android-tcp-server-and-client

But every time I try to establish a connection the memory uses is increased by about 500KB, so if the client disconnects and then reconnects without closing the application after many attempts the memory becomes saturated.

I have already tried various methods including
`cancel (true)` in `AsyncTask's` `doInbackground`,
close and force the socket and in, out objects to null
call `System.gc ()`
but none of this worked.

Comment: This entire code looks very ugly to me, since it uses a lot of static fields. It's also rather old (4 years), so I would look for something more up to date instead of trying to make it work.

Comment: @Pawel, I understand what you mean. Unfortunately I did not find anything more up to date that would meet my needs and the available sources. Beyond the problem of memory the code works and I can communicate between different devices simultaneously and also with Windows of which I have already written a code working in Delphi. Do you know some written example better? If so, pass it to me, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but try to invoke AsyncTask as

```
new InitTCPClientTask().execute(new Void[0]);
```

instead of

```
InitTCPClientTask task = new InitTCPClientTask();
task.execute(new Void[0]);
```

Comment: Writing the code one way or another doesn't change the result. You wrote exactly the same thing another way